# R - How to sort age values into age group

Tags: r

Hi I created a group of age bins in R:

```
labs <- c(paste(0, "", sep=""), paste(1,9, sep="-"),paste(seq(10, 80, by = 10), seq(20-1, 90-1, by =10), sep="-", paste(90, "+", sep=""))

out "0" "1-9" "10-19" "20-29" "30-39" "40-49" "50-59" "60-69" "70-79" "80-89" "90+"
```

How can I sort a column of ages from a df into the appropriate age group in labs? How can I use cut function?

Expected Output will be:

```
Age AgeGroup
5   1-9
0   0
15  10-19
69  70-79
100 90+
```

Comment: What is your expected output.  What you need is `cut(age, breaks = c(1, seq(10, 90, by = 10), Inf))`

Comment: have added expected output above

Comment: i encounter Error in cut.default(df$Age, breaks = c(1, seq(10, 90, by = 10), : 'x' must be numeric

Comment: is your age column numeric? if not do `df$Age <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Age))`

Comment: I would suggest to convert the 'Age' to `numeric`

Comment: hi akrun your code `cut(age, breaks = c(1, seq(10, 90, by = 10), Inf))` works after i converted it to numeric :) but I'm getting the output in a strange format as (30,40] (70,80]. Wondering what's causing this? I tried `cut(age, breaks = c(1, seq(10, 90, by = 10), Iabels = labs, right = FALSE))` but still the same strange format. I would like it to be in the format (30-40), (70-80)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Set seed for reproducibility of results since I use sample() function 
# to generate values for Age variable
set.seed(12345)

#create a numeric variable Age       
Age <- sample(0:110, 100, replace = TRUE)


# Use cut() function to associate each value with a specific age group
AgeGroup <- cut(Age, 
                right=FALSE, 
                breaks = c(0,1,(1:9)*10,1000),
                labels = c("0","1-9",
                           paste((1:8)*10,"-",(1:8 + 1)*10 -1),"90+"))

# create a data frame (if necessary)
df <- data.frame(Age, AgeGroup)
head(df)

# 1  80  80 - 89
# 2  97      90+
# 3  84  80 - 89
# 4  98      90+
# 5  50  50 - 59
# 6  18  10 - 19
```

Comment: Hi Katia your code works well! Just one issue, the values of age = 0, 10, 20 etc didn't seem to be sorted correctly. Need to add `right = FALSE` for it to work. Thanks!

Comment: @spidermarn Hi, You are absolutely right. And I made this edit right away, but somehow it did not get saved (I might have forgotten to click "save" button. I have made the change again and it should be there now. Thanks for noticing it. --Katia